# mod_rewrite rules in a separate configuration file (Aegir)

Tags: mod-rewrite, virtualhost, apache-2.2

I got a virtual host configuration file I cannot edit or modify directly, since it's generated by our hosting platform, [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/). But it does have `Include pre.d` and `Include post.d` statements that are included before and after the vhost-configuration.

What I'd like to do, is to add vhost-specific rewrite-rules in separate files, so they can automatically get migrated when we add new servers to the clusters.

So in `pre.d` I create a file called `ServerName_redirects.conf`, where I put the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^servername.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/*(.*)$ https://servername.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

This is just one of many rules that will be used during migration of the site to a new platform. But it doesn't work, until I wrap it in a `<VirtualHost servername.com:80>`-block. But since VirtualHost-blocks does not inherit `DocumentRoot` and `ServerName` from the original vhost's configuration, all URL's will just end up as 404's in the end, unless they redirect traffic to an external site.

And I cannot simply add `DocumentRoot` or `ServerName` to the ServerName_redirects.conf-file, since these are "dynamic", and can change at any point in time when we move the site between servers or platforms in Aegir.

Although a `.htaccess` in every `DocumentRoot` would solve the problem, I can't use that either since it's a Drupal multi-site setup, and I'd would have to put every site's rewrite rule in the same `.htaccess` file with a `RequestCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site-1.com$` for each rule, which isn't especially elegant and I'm worried how it would affect the performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Comment: why don't use a .htaccess file ?

Comment: GregD: It's not a duplicate, because that article does only cover the syntax/usage of mod_rewrite, and this is primarily a Apache2.2 configuration question.

Comment: silviud: I can't use a .htaccess-file, because that's also generated by the hosting-platform.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your hosting environment, I can't give you a definite answer to your question. However, I am thinking you might find a solution to your problem on Apache's [Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html) page. If I am understanding your problem correctly, and I hope I am, you might be able to do something similar to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/*(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%0/docs
    VirtualScriptAlias /www/hosts/%0/cgi-bin 
</VirtualHost>
```

You'd have to tweak your VirtualDocumentRoot and VirtualScriptAlias lines to fit your environment, but the details for doing so are in the [Apache docs for mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html). Again, I'm hoping I am understanding your problem correctly, and I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That didn't solve the problem, but it was a good try... The problem is that the site get's moved between directories because of platforms/codebases, so when doing a migration of a new version of the site it get's moved from `/www/platform-1.0/sites/site-1.com` to `/www/platform-1.1/sites/site-1.com`

Answer (score 0):

Create a [hook].drush.inc file in /var/aegir/.drush/ to hold a function that will alter the vhost when it's generated.  Implement the Drush hook `hook_provision_apache_vhost_config($uri, $data)` provided by Provision.  `$uri` is the site being verified, same as the site name in Aegir.  You can return either a string that should be injected into the vhost or an array of strings.  Aegir will invoke that hook whenever it verifies a site.

Unlike my example below, I usually return something like `"Include /etc/apache2/example.com.conf"` so that I can change the configuration without needing to verify the site; I can just restart Apache.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_provision_apache_vhost_config().
 *
 * Insert custom vhost configurations into Aegir's template.
 */
function example_provision_apache_vhost_config($uri, $data) {
  if ($uri == 'example.com') {
    return "
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

";
  }
}
```

See http://docs.aegirproject.org/en/3.x/extend/altering-behaviours/#injecting-into-site-vhosts.